# MonkeyRunner and androidviewclient "dump-all-windows-lib.py" example is not working

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm running [this](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/dump-all-windows-lib.py) example, but it keeps showing this error:

```
windows = vc.list()
  File "/Users/ehsan/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130514/sdk/tools/androidviewclient-2.3.24.jar/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient$py.class", line 1864, in list
Exception: Not implemented yet: listing windows with UiAutomator
```

I can run other examples but I don't know what is the problem.
and this is how I run the example:

```
monkeyrunner -plugin androidviewclient-2.3.24.jar dump-all-windows-lib.py
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The *list* command has not been implemented yet for **UiAutomator** back-end.
You can force the use of **ViewServer** back-end if you really need it.